# How to pass SCSI command to hard disk on Vmware ESXi (6.0)

Tags: linux, io, vmware, ioctl, esxi

I want to develop an application to pass SCSI command to hard disk using C language.
In Linux, when pass SCSI or other command to device, we just use ioctl() function to do it.
But hard disk device node was not showed as /dev/sdx on VMware ESXi just like Linux does,
So How can I pass these command to device on VMware ESXi just like doing it on Linux.

Comment: Do you want to initiate SCSI commands from ESXi or from a Linux virtual machine running on VMware ESXi?

Comment: From ESXi. This Application is designed to run on ESXi directly.

Comment: I think it will be more difficult to pass SCSI commands from Linux virtual machine running on ESXi.